# Column Headings in an Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive report which needs to display different data based on value selected in a select list.

Interactive report is displaying data from a generic table, but what data is stored in which column depends on ID selected in the select list. What values does a column hold for any ID is stored in another table. Is there any way I can have column headings from my definition table, and data from the generic table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page help indicates that Column Heading for Interactive Report supports Application, Page Items and System Variables. 
So if you want the column header to display the value of item P1_COL1_HEADER then you would put `&P1_COL1_HEADER.` as value. The leading "&" and trailing "." are important.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: Also, is there a way by which I can choose which columns to be made visible based on values in P1_COL1_HEADER. For example, if P1_COL1_HEADER has value 3, then show columns 2,4,6 and if value is 2 then show columns 1,3,5?

Comment: Have a look at the "Server-side Condition" for the column. You can configure there when the column needs to be displayed/hidden